# 404 error on cyrillic url

Tags: urls

I am using Another Wordpress Classifieds Plugin (awpcp) with Ukrainian translation. Due to it's limitations I am forced to use Cyrillic urls. While the site navigation works perfectly, when I reload some pages or create an external link to those pages I receive a 404 error.

Normalize URLs 1.1 Plugin fixes problem completely, but for some reason my homepage stops loading..

Site is hosted on Hostgator shared hosting with php 5.3 enabled. Wordpress version is WordPress Uk 3.4.3-alpha.

To access problematic page please click "Куплю (0)" category on the following page:
[ukrcoins.com/дошка-оголошень/](http://ukrcoins.com/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C/)

Please, advice a possible solution. Thanks!
Getting a Normalize URLs 1.1 Plugin to work seems to be the easiest way.

Comment: It says that your category have no ads inside, which is true (0) and I don't fall upon a 404. But the URL look strange `/дошка-оголошень/перегляд-оголошень/2/куплю/` did you check rewrite rules and pagination ?

Comment: I can confirm that there is no 404 error . your category is just empty ...

Comment: It doesn't give 404 for the first time, but only if you reload the page.

After some researching it seems I've found a problem. When link is clicked path is converted using percent-encoding and looks like this:
http://ukrcoins.com/%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%88%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c/%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b4-%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c/2/%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bb%d1%8e/

But, when browser reloads the page or a url is copied, path is converted to uppercase and I receive a 404
Can anybody suggest a fix?

Comment: Fixed the problem with Normilize URLs plugin. Had to remove:
 isset( $path ) && $path == '/' && $path = '';
string to make plugin work on my server. I would appreciate if somebody could it explain why it caused problems.

Answer (score -1):

add Check if parameters exist in your web.config globalization tag

```
  <globalization
  requestEncoding="utf-8"
  responseEncoding="utf-8"
  responseHeaderEncoding="utf-8"
  fileEncoding="utf-8"
  resourceProviderFactoryType=""
  enableBestFitResponseEncoding="true"/>
```

Comment: I am not familiar with web.config. I googled it and it appears that it's used on Windows servers? If so what can I do on Linux server? Should I enter code from above to .htaccess?

Comment: Both server and WordPress installation are configured to use utf8.